# How can i call a function in navigation layout from my main.py

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

Hello i was trying to call a function in a screen under navigation layout from my main.py but its showing an Attribute error.

Although the code is running,but gives an error on pressing "plot" button in line screen.

The Error is: AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'get_data'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 162, in <module>
     Graphs().run()
   File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 308, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/home/saurabh/Desktop/BHUVNESH/Programming/graphs/environments/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivymd/uix/behaviors/ripplebehavior.py", line 245, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "/home/saurabh/Desktop/BHUVNESH/Programming/graphs/environments/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivymd/uix/button.py", line 1083, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "/home/saurabh/Desktop/BHUVNESH/Programming/graphs/environments/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivymd/uix/button.py", line 969, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "<string>", line 214, in <module>
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'get_data'
```

I did a bit research about this error and tried other methods to call but couldn't find a solution. Please Help.

python version:v3.7.8
kivy version:v2.0.0
kivymd:v0.104.1

<main.py>

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton, MDTextButton,MDFillRoundFlatButton
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager,FallOutTransition
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineListItem,OneLineIconListItem
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.lang import Builder
from navigation import screen_helper
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.core.window import Window
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


xpoints, ypoints = list(), list()

class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ListScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LineScreen(Screen):
    
    def get_data(self,root):
        
        t = self.ids.n.text
        x1 = self.ids.x_label.text
        y1 = self.ids.y_label.text
        
        e1 = (self.ids.A.text)
        e2 = (self.ids.B.text)
        e3 = (self.ids.C.text)
        e4 = (self.ids.D.text)
        e5 = (self.ids.E.text)
        
        e6 = (self.ids.F.text)
        e7 = (self.ids.G.text)
        e8 = (self.ids.H.text)
        e9 = (self.ids.I.text)
        e10 = (self.ids.J.text)
        xpoints=[e1,e2,e3,e4,e5]
        ypoints=[e6,e7,e8,e9,e10]
        xpoints.sort()
        ypoints.sort()
        
        plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints, marker='o')
        plt.title(t)
        plt.xlabel(x1)
        plt.ylabel(y1)
        plt.draw()
        plt.savefig("test.png")
        plt.show()

class BarScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScatterScreen(Screen):
    pass


class PieScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SineScreen(Screen):
    pass


class CosineScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager(transition=FallOutTransition())
sm.add_widget(WelcomeScreen(name='welcome'))
sm.add_widget(ListScreen(name='list'))
sm.add_widget(LineScreen(name='line'))
sm.add_widget(BarScreen(name='bar'))
sm.add_widget(ScatterScreen(name='scatter'))
sm.add_widget(PieScreen(name='pie'))
sm.add_widget(SineScreen(name='sine'))
sm.add_widget(CosineScreen(name='cosine'))




class Graphs(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):

        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)

        return screen

    

Graphs().run()
```

<navigation.py>

```
screen_helper = """

Screen:

    NavigationLayout:
    
        ScreenManager:
            
            id:screen_manager
            
            WelcomeScreen:
                name:'welcome'
                Image:
                    source:"g.png"
                    allow_stretch:True
                    keep_ratio:False
                    
                MDLabel:
                    text:'Hello!'
                    font_size:54
                    halign:'center'
                    theme_text_color:'Primary'    
                
                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    text:'CONTINUE'
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.1}
                    elevation_normal: 12
                    on_press:screen_manager.current='home'
            ListScreen:
                name: 'list'
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Graphs'
                        left_action_items: [["menu",lambda x: navigation.set_state('open')]]
                        elevation: 10

                    ScrollView:
                        MDList:
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text:'Line Graph'
                                size: 
                                on_press:screen_manager.current='line'
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'lineicon.png'
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text:'Bar Graph'
                                on_press:screen_manager.current='bar'
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'baricon.png'
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text:'Scatter Graph'
                                on_press:screen_manager.current='scatter'
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'scattericon.png'
                            OneLineIconListItem:    
                                text:'Pie Chart'
                                on_press:screen_manager.current='pie'
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'pieicon.png'
                            OneLineIconListItem:    
                                text:'Sine Wave'
                                on_press:screen_manager.current='sine'
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'sineicon.png'
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text:'Cosine Wave'
                                on_press:screen_manager.current='cosine'
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'cosicon.png' 
                MDRaisedButton:
                    text:'Back'
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
                    on_press:screen_manager.current='home'   
                
            LineScreen:
                name:'line'
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Line Graph'
                        left_action_items: [["menu",lambda x: navigation.set_state('open')]]
                        elevation: 10
                    Image:
                        source:"line.png"
                        allow_stretch:True
                        keep_ratio:False
                    
                    
        
                MDTextField:
                    id:n
                    hint_text:"Enter Title of Graph"
                    mode: "rectangle"
                    helper_text_mode:"on_error"
                    required:True
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.81}
                    size_hint_x:.4
                    width:150

                MDTextField:
                    id:x_label
                    hint_text:"Enter X Label"
                    mode: "rectangle"
                    helper_text_mode:"on_error"
                    required:True
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.71}
                    size_hint_x:.4
                    width:150    
                        
                MDTextField:
                    id:y_label
                    hint_text:"Enter Y Label"
                    mode: "rectangle"
                    helper_text_mode:"on_error"
                    required:True
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.61}
                    size_hint_x:.4
                    width:150       
                    
                MDTextField:
                    id:A
                    input_filter:'int'
                    hint_text:"X1"
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.3,'center_y':0.52}
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width:30  
                MDTextField:
                    id:B
                    input_filter:'int'
                    hint_text:"X2"
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.3,'center_y':0.44}
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width:30
                MDTextField:
                    id:C
                    input_filter:'int'
                    hint_text:"X3"
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.3,'center_y':0.36}
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width:30
                MDTextField:
                    id:D
                    input_filter:'int'
                    hint_text:"X4"
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.3,'center_y':0.28}
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width:30
                MDTextField:
                    id:E
                    input_filter:'int'
                    hint_text:"X5"
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.3,'center_y':0.2}
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width:30                      
                MDTextField:  
                    id:F 
                    input_filter:'int'
                    hint_text:"Y1"
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.7,'center_y':0.52}
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width:30 
                MDTextField:
                    id:G   
                    input_filter:'int'
                    hint_text:"Y2"
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.7,'center_y':0.44}
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width:30
                MDTextField:
                    id:H   
                    input_filter:'int'
                    hint_text:"Y3"
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.7,'center_y':0.36}
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width:30
                MDTextField:
                    id:I   
                    input_filter:'int'
                    hint_text:"Y4"
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.7,'center_y':0.28}
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width:30
                MDTextField:
                    id:J   
                    input_filter:'int'
                    hint_text:"Y5"
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.7,'center_y':0.2}
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width:30             
            
                        
                MDRaisedButton:
                    text:'Back'
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2,'center_y':0.1}
                    on_press:screen_manager.current='list' 
                                
                MDRaisedButton:
                    text:"Plot "    
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.1}
                    on_press:root.get_data(root)

                    
                            
            BarScreen:
                name:'bar'
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Bar Graph'
                        left_action_items: [["menu",lambda x: navigation.set_state('open')]]
                        elevation: 10
                    
                    Image:
                        source:"bar.png"
                        allow_stretch:True
                        keep_ratio:False
        
        
                MDRaisedButton:
                    text:'Back'
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
                    on_press:screen_manager.current='list'    
            
        
            ScatterScreen:
                name:'scatter'
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Scatter Graph'
                        left_action_items: [["menu",lambda x: navigation.set_state('open')]]
                        elevation: 10
                    
                    Image:
                        source:"scatter.png"
                        allow_stretch:True
                        keep_ratio:False
        
        
        
                MDRaisedButton:
                    text:'Back'
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
                    on_press:screen_manager.current='list'  
            
            PieScreen:
                name:'pie'
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Pie Chart'
                        left_action_items: [["menu",lambda x: navigation.set_state('open')]]
                        elevation: 10
                    
                    Image:
                        source:"pie.png"
                        allow_stretch:True
                        keep_ratio:False
        
        
                
                MDRaisedButton:
                    text:'Back'
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
                    on_press:screen_manager.current='list'

            SineScreen:
                name:'sine'
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Sine Wave'
                        left_action_items: [["menu",lambda x: navigation.set_state('open')]]
                        elevation: 10
                    
                    Image:
                        source:"sine.png"
                        allow_stretch:True
                        keep_ratio:True
        
        
        
                MDRaisedButton:
                    text:'Back'
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
                    on_press:screen_manager.current='list'        


            CosineScreen:
                name:'cosine'
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Cosine Wave'
                        left_action_items: [["menu",lambda x: navigation.set_state('open')]]
                        elevation: 10
                    
                    Image:
                        source:"cos.png"
                        allow_stretch:True
                        keep_ratio:True
        
        
        
                MDRaisedButton:
                    text:'Back'
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
                    on_press:screen_manager.current='list'

            
            Screen:
                name: 'home'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Home'
                        left_action_items: [["menu",lambda x: navigation.set_state('open')]]
                        elevation: 10

                    Image:
                        source:"home1.png"
                        allow_stretch:True
                        keep_ratio:False

            
            Screen:
                name: 'about'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'About'
                        left_action_items: [["menu",lambda x: navigation.set_state('open')]]
                        opening_time: 0.05
                        elevation: 10

                    Image:
                        source:"home1.png"
                        allow_stretch:True
                        keep_ratio:False


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id:navigation
            
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
            
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: '3dp'
                    
                    Image:
                        source: 'goku.jpg'
                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'Basic Graph Plotter'
                        font_style: 'H5'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height : self.texture_size[1]

                    ScrollView:
                        MDList:
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: 'Home'
                                on_press:
                                    navigation.set_state('close')
                                    closing_time: 0.05
                                    screen_manager.current='home'
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'home.png'
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: 'Graphs'
                                on_press:
                                    navigation.set_state('close')
                                    closing_time: 0.05
                                    screen_manager.current='list' 
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'graphs.png'      
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: 'About' 
                                on_press:
                                    navigation.set_state('close')
                                    closing_time: 0.05
                                    screen_manager.current='about'
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'about.png'   

"""
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You haven't defined the attribute ```self.ids``` anywhere in your ```Graph()``` class

Comment: @ewong i have uploaded another code with another method could you help me out with this ,please?

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Comment: @ewong included